# How to edit /etc/inittab?

Tags: linux, files, vi, gedit

I want to edit `/etc/inittab` in order to get a login prompt on the serial console once the system boots. By default, inittab file complains to be `ro`.

I tried both `gksudo gedit /etc/inittab` and `sudo vi /etc/inittab` and seemed to be properly configured. However, when I opened file after that with gedit, I saw no difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Open terminal, then type `su` and type your root user password. After this:

```
vi /etc/inittab
```

In my case this works but I'm using CentOS.

Comment: From your question it sounds like you weren't saving before exiting Vi.  After you are done editing in `vi` you need to save changes, typically with an [Esc] then `w` (to write changes), you can combine with `q` as follows: `wq!` (write, quit, and ! means don't confirm).

Comment: Yes, after changes you should type: wq :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want a serial console, I suppose your using some embedded device. So I guess the partition /etc/inittab is on is mounted read only.

You'd have to remount the partition writable.

Use `mount` without arguments to figure out what partition the file is on and use something like  `mount -o remount,rw /etc/` to remount it writable.

Answer (score 0):

You must also do # `update-initramfs -u`, to my understanding, to have the changes take effect (on Debian Linux, anyway).